# Motion tracking a shot where no tracking point is in frame throughout the video

Tags: tracking, motion-capture

I’m trying to motion track a shot where the position it ends on is totally different from the starting position. In other words there are no tracking points that stay throughout the whole video.

How can I set up a tracking scene for the whole video instead of just part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in this situation.  All you need to do:

1. is in solve settings set **keyframe A** and **keyframe B** where you have enough motion and more then 8 point are the same.  So it can be not the start and end frame.
2. And also you need to track points from start and end (and maybe in middle) - your goal is to make shure that every frame have 8 or more enabled tracking points. They may be different, but due to the fact that new markers pick up motion, tracking will continue